# How do I change the color of the indicator applet to green?

Tags: 11.04, indicator, colors

I want to change the indicator app's color from "blue" to "green" again. In 10.04 all notifications were in green, 11.04 now has blue color notification.

How can I change it back to green?

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The indicator colouring is a deliberate change by the Canonical design team - see [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-mono/+bug/740900)

To summarise -

- Red: denotes critical issues
- Orange: denotes critical warnings
- Blue: denotes pure information.
- Green denotes that something is "now OK", or "approved".

Hence the message indicator was changed to blue to indicate just "information".

Thus, I think the only way to change back to green is to replace the ubuntu-mono package with a version from maverick or lucid.  Not sure whether this is advisable though.

Answer (score 1):

[Instructions are available under this link](http://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/changing-new-message-indicator-color/). This works for both 11.10 and 12.04.

Also, you may find [this post on OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/03/omg-replacement-coloured-indicator-message-alert-icons-for-lucid/) useful.