# Why does the sound icon turn blue sometimes?

Tags: indicator-sound

The sound indicator icon turns blue sometimes:

[image: screenshot]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The blue sound menu icon means that at least one application is trying to output sound but is unable to do so because the sound is muted.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39831/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-indicator-applet-to-green) and my answer there.  To summarise

```
Red: denotes critical issues
Orange: denotes critical warnings
Blue: denotes pure information.
Green denotes that something is "now OK", or "approved".
```

Hence the sound indicator is blue to indicate just "information" i.e. something has happened.

What this "information" is depends on the indicator - the [ayantana team](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-mono/+bug/740900) didnt specify where this "information" should be reported.

Comment: How would I go about acquiring said information?

Comment: dont think you can - see my edit.  Maybe a question (bug report) on launchpad.  Sounds like the design team needs to consider this more.