# How to change messaging menu's indicator icon?

Tags: messaging-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the color of the indicator applet to green?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39831/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-indicator-applet-to-green)

How to change the recent notifications indicator icon ?

I do not really like the default icon which turns into a green mailbox when i have an unread notification.

Comment: I was not actually talking about messaging menu
I was looking to change icon of recent notifications.

I found the icons at /usr/share/libindicator/icons/hicolor/scalable